# summing a transformation of a list of numbers in scala

Tags: scala

I frequently need to sum the transformation of a list of numbers in Scala.  One way to do this of course is:

```
list.map(transform(_)).sum
```

However, this creates memory when creating memory is not required.  An alternative is to fold the list.

```
list.foldLeft(0.0) { (total, x) => total + f(x) }
```

I find the first expression far easier to write than the second expression.  Is there a method I can use that has the ease of the first with the efficiency of the second?  Or am I better off writing my own implicit method?

```
list.mapSum(transform(_))
```

Comment: Only tangentially related, but be careful if summing transformations over **sets**, e.g.: `Set(1,2,3).map(_ % 2).sum` is `1`, not `2`. I recently got bitten by something like `setOfPlayers.map(_.salary).sum`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a *view* to make your transformer methods (map, filter...) lazy. See [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) for more information.

So for example in your case of a method called `transform`, you would write

```
list.view.map(transform).sum
```

(note you can optionally omit the `(_)`)

Comment: I had remembered this, but some faulty testing convinced me this was making things slower.  Today, after some more playing around, `view` seems great!

Comment: @schmmd in some trivial cases implementing a `view` will make things slower, which might be why it isn't automagically applied by default. I think it depends on factors like the proportion of the elements you're using / filtering out. Also speed != memory. So the best thing is probably to try it and benchmark, if speed is critical.

Comment: I should just use an iterator in this example.

Comment: @schmmd That's certainly an option where you only need to deal with the whole list, or the first n elements. Views are more flexible insofar as you can access elements randomly as many times as you want. Iterators come from imperative programming and have mutable state, so are generally best avoided in functional code.

Comment: Well understood, but views are considered extremely problematic in scala to the point that many people want to remove them, so I avoid them.

Answer (score 5):

This operation is called `foldMap`, and you can find it in Scalaz.

```
list foldMap transform
```

Comment: +1 when I start using scalaz, my future replacement will really hate me.

Comment: As given, this expression doesn't sum elements, does it?

Comment: To elaborate further, `foldMap` has the following type signature: `def foldMap[A, M: Monoid](t: F[A], f: A => M): M`, so your transform has to return something that is a Monoid, and hence, has a "zero" and a `|+|` operation, which `foldMap` will use to accumulate a result.

Comment: @Zwirb in that signature there are two parameters, but I only see one argument in the answer. What is `F[A]`?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: you're right! I quoted the method def from the `Foldable` trait instead of the one in the `MA` trait, which is the one that is actually used here (and ends up calling the method in `Foldable`): `def foldMap[B](f: A => B)(implicit r: Foldable[M], m: Monoid[B]): B = r.foldMap(value, f)`, where `value` is your original list that got pimped into something with the `MA` trait. It's also confusing to me, btw: I'm barely starting to find my way around scalaz...