# Deforestation in Scala collections

Tags: scala, collections, implicits

From the design of Scala's collections I understand that something like:

```
scala> BitSet(1,2,3) map (_ + "a")
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(1a, 2a, 3a)
```

doesn't build an intermediate datastructure: the new Set is built as the BitSet is iterated over using a Builder. In fact in that case it is obvious since a bitset of strings doesn't make sense.

What about maps from lists? I am pretty sure that the following builds an intermediate list:

```
scala> List(1,2,3) map (_ -> "foo") toMap
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] =
    Map(1 -> foo, 2 -> foo, 3 -> foo)
```

namely the list `List((1,foo), (2,foo), (3,foo))`. If not, then how? Now, what about the following?

```
scala> Map.empty ++ (List(1,2,3) map (_ -> "foo"))
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] =
    Map(1 -> foo, 2 -> foo, 3 -> foo)
```

This time, from what I seem to understand from the type of `++`:

```
def ++ [B >: (A, B), That]
       (that: TraversableOnce[B])
       (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[A, B], B, That]): That
```

I *think* it might be the case that the map is built on the fly, and that no intermediate list is constructed.

Is it the case? If yes, is this the canonical way of ensuring deforestation or is there a more straightforward syntax?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `breakOut` to ensure that no intermediate collection is created. For example:

```
// creates intermediate list.
scala> List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap).toMap 
res542: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 3, 11 -> 9)

scala> import collection.breakOut
import collection.breakOut

// doesn't create an intermediate list.
scala> List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)(breakOut) : Map[Int, Int]
res543: Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 3, 11 -> 9)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).

**UPDATE:**

If you read the definition of `breakOut`, you'll notice that it's basically a way of creating a `CanBuildFrom` object of expected type and passing it explicitly to the method. `breakOut` merely saves you from typing the following boilerplate.

```
// Observe the error message. This will tell you the type of argument expected.
scala> List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)('dummy)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Symbol
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[(Int, Int)],(Int, Int),?]
              List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)('dummy)
                                                ^

// Let's try passing the implicit with required type.
// (implicitly[T] simply picks up an implicit object of type T from scope.)
scala> List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)(implicitly[CanBuildFrom[List[(Int, Int)], (Int, Int), Map[Int, Int]]])
// Oops! It seems the implicit with required type doesn't exist.
<console>:16: error: Cannot construct a collection of type Map[Int,Int] with elements of type (Int, Int) based on a coll
ection of type List[(Int, Int)].
              List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)(implicitly[CanBuildFrom[List[(Int, Int)], (Int, Int), Map[Int, Int]]])

// Let's create an object of the required type ...
scala> object Bob extends CanBuildFrom[List[(Int, Int)], (Int, Int), Map[Int, Int]] {
     |   def apply(from: List[(Int, Int)]) = foo.apply
     |   def apply() = foo.apply
     |   private def foo = implicitly[CanBuildFrom[Nothing, (Int, Int), Map[Int, Int]]]
     | }
defined module Bob

// ... and pass it explicitly.
scala> List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)(Bob)
res12: Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 3, 11 -> 9)

// Or let's just have breakOut do all the hard work for us.
scala> List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap)(breakOut) : Map[Int, Int]
res13: Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 3, 11 -> 9)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. What I'm not sure of is why scala complains about `List((3, 4), (9, 11)).map(_.swap) : Map[Int,Int]` instead of using the type constraint I have explicitly put to pick the right implicit (exactly as read picks the right typeclass instance in haskell depending on the context). Is it just that implicit don't work that way (I would totally understand it, I know subtyping makes everything hard) or did I overlook something in that special case?

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: I haven't closed the REPL since past 5 days. I use it heavily in my everyday development. :-)

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: My Windows finally crashed. :-D

Comment: @missingfaktor My fault I'm sure http://www.lotusmuseum.com/files/Mousepad_VIP_Dilbert.JPG

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: LOL. Good one. :-)

Comment: So there's no `implicitly[CanBuildFrom[List[(Int, Int)], (Int, Int), Map[Int, Int]]]` in scope but there is a `implicitly[CanBuildFrom[Nothing, (Int, Int), Map[Int, Int]]]`. Is that right?

Comment: Ok, I see, Nothing is a marker to say "not from any collection". It could as well be Foo it wouldn't change anything, as long as it doesn't clash with a collection, and that the convention is respected by everyone so that breakOut can pick it.

Comment: @PaulBrauner: Yes, you can think about it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1) Correct, there's no intermediate List

2) Yes, you get an itermediate List.

3) Again yes, you get an intermeditate List from what you have in the parentheses. There's no "magic" going on. If you have something in parentheses, it gets evaluated first.

I'm not sure what you mean by "deforestation" here: according to Wikipedia it means eliminating tree structures. If you mean eliminating intermediate lists, you should use a *view*. See for example here: [summing a transformation of a list of numbers in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729801/summing-a-transformation-of-a-list-of-numbers-in-scala/7729934#7729934)

So without intermediate results, your examples would be

```
BitSet(1,2,3).view.map(_ + "a").toSet
```

(`toSet` is required because otherwise you have an `IterableView[String,Iterable[_]]`)

```
List(1,2,3).view.map(_ -> "foo").toMap

Map.empty ++ (List(1,2,3).view.map(_ -> "foo"))
```

There is also a `force` method for executing the transformation operations, but this seems to have a nasty habit of giving you a more general type back (perhaps someone can comment with a reason):

```
scala> Set(1,2,3).view.map(_ + 1).force
res23: Iterable[Int] = Set(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Deforestation means eliminating intermediate tree structures. A list is just a degenerate tree where the each node `::` has an element leaf as the left child and either another `::` node or a `Nil` leaf as the right child, so the term can be applied to lists as well.

Comment: Thanks. About 3) I was not expecting magic to happen but I was hoping the typing context would lead ++ into picking the right implicit for the job (exactly like read picks the right typeclass instance in haskell).